# Simple drop down menu design

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have designed a simple menu for my WordPress site as follows without using any classes or IDs:

```
<div class="main-menu">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="menu-link">home</a>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a href="#" class="menu-link">product</a>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#">XXXX</a>
          </li>

          <li>
            <a href="#">XXXX</a>
          </li>

          <li>
            <a href="#">ZZZZ</a>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a href="#">XXXX</a>
              </li>

              <li>
                <a href="#">XXXX</a>
              </li>

              <li>
                <a href="#">XXXX</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a href="#" class="menu-link">more</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

And I hid the sub-menu using the following style:

```
.main-menu ul li ul {
    display: none;
}
```

The script code that I previously used for menus that had a class or ID is as follows:

```
$('.menu').click(function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    $(".mini_menu").show();
});
```

But now I want a script code that, when the user clicks on any of the li's,  the sub menu to appear if there is one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `li` click use `$(this)` with `children('ul')` to show your menu without using class.

Example:

```js
$('.main-menu').find('li').click(function(evt) {
  evt.stopPropagation();
  $(this).children('ul').toggle();

});
```

```css
.main-menu ul li ul {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-menu">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="menu-link">home</a>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a href="#" class="menu-link">product</a>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#">XXXX</a>
          </li>

          <li>
            <a href="#">XXXX</a>
          </li>

          <li>
            <a href="#">ZZZZ</a>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a href="#">XXXX</a>
              </li>

              <li>
                <a href="#">XXXX</a>
              </li>

              <li>
                <a href="#">XXXX</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a href="#" class="menu-link">more</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. But another problem that I have is that after clicking on li, it opens under the menu, but it doesn't close anymore? That is, when I click on a part except the opened sub-menu, I want the opened sub-menu to close.

Comment: use `evt.stopPropagation();` with `toggle()`. See updated answer.